Example of a finitely generated metabelian group whose Fitting subgroup is not nilpotent
It is known that the Fitting subgroup of a finitely generated polycyclic-by-finite group is nilpotent, but this statement is not true for the solvable group.
It is clear that both Lamplighter groups and $BS(1,k)$ groups have Fitting subgroups being infinitely generated abelian. I was wondering if there are any examples of a finitely generated metabelian group whose Fitting subgroup is not nilpotent?
(copied from Math StackExchange)

A f.g. metabelian group has max-n (Ph. Hall in the 50s) so its Fitting subgroup is nilpotent. This is more generally true for max-n groups, hence abelian-by-nilpotent f.g. groups (Ph. Hall) and abelian-by-polycyclic (Roseblade).

Thank you again Yves.

@YCor My deleted answer was erroneous, but isn't it true that finitely generated linear group (or weakly linear, in sense of having faithful rep over finite product of fields) is still max-n?

@DenisT I thought about it while posting my answer and I'm positive about it, but I'd need to think more. This might be worth a separate question.

For context: the Fitting subgroup of a group is the union of its nilpotent normal subgroups. This a filtering union, hence is a subgroup, by construction locally nilpotent.
To answer the question: a f.g. metabelian group has max-n (Ph. Hall in the 50s) so its Fitting subgroup is nilpotent.
This is more generally true for max-n groups, hence holds for abelian-by-nilpotent f.g. groups (Ph. Hall) and abelian-by-polycyclic f.g. groups (Roseblade).
